# Redirect output of gnome-terminal to file

Tags: bash, shell, redirection, gnome-terminal

I have written a script which opens a new terminal using gnome-terminal. The output shown on gnome-terminal is correct. I want this output should be in some file.  I have tried this:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "{ /usr/local/bin/kedr_capture_trace -b ; exec bash; }"' > outputfile   &
```

But it's not working. The output shown by gnome-terminal is correct but not captured in 
 `outputfile`.

I have tried this too:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "{ /usr/local/bin/kedr_capture_trace -b ; exec bash; } > outputfile"'   &
```

But in this case output is not shown by `gnome-terminal`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just what is the use of a terminal that doesn't output anything to screen?

Comment: Yes, provide an answer to the question "What are you _really_ trying to do?" in the original post, please.

Comment: You should register your account on Super User to become owner of this question again. Suggesting edits won't help much along the way, because you can't post comments here.

Answer (score 2):

The shell is responsible for file redirection, not the terminal

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "{ echo foo; echo bar; exec bash; } > outputfile"'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the command `script` might be what you want.